# Fill all options of an Enum into Nullable<Enum> array

Tags: c#, arrays, enums

I have an `Enum` that needs to go into an `Array` that is `Nullable`:

```
StatusType?[] statusTypes = null; //Array to fill
```

I tried to fill the `statusTypes` like this:

```
statusTypes = (StatusType?[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(StatusType))
```

I receive the following error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'x.Entities.Enums.StatusType[]' to type 'System.Nullable`1[x.Entities.Enums.StatusType][]'.'

How can I fill the `Enum?[]` with `Enum[]`?  I'm sure it is any easy fix, but I have been stumpted on it for a bit now.  Thank you.

Comment: Conceptually, there are two ways to turn a bunch of `Enum`s into a `Enum?[]`. One is to combine your values into an `Enum[]` , then convert that to an `Enum?[]`. As you have seen, that is not possible. The correct approach, as shown by the answers, is the other one: first convert each `Enum` into an `Enum?` separately, then combine those into an `Enum?[]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use LINQ's `Cast<T>()` extension method and provide the target type:

```
statusTypes = Enum.GetValues(typeof(StatusType)).Cast<StatusType?>().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just cast the arrays. The types are not compatible. You can use [`Array.ConvertAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53(v=vs.110).aspx) to do the convertion:

```
Array.ConvertAll((StatusType[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(StatusType)), x => (StatusType?)x);
```

Comment: Thank you, looks like it worked with a slight change, needed to specifiy `<TInput, TOutput>` and `(StatusType[])` before `Enum.GetTypes`, now it looks like this: `statusTypes = Array.ConvertAll<StatusType, StatusType?>((StatusType[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(StatusType)), x => (StatusType?)x);`